# Trouble hiding backbarbutton text

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, navigationitem

For some reason this code won't hide back button text.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)}
```

Text remains "Back".

On the other hand executing:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton
```

does hide the button. I execute both inside viewDidLoad. Any ideas how to remove that text and keep the arrow only? I read the suggestions on this site already.

Comment: Did not work :-( This kills me.

Comment: Tested my answer below and works for me

Comment: I do appreciate your answer. None of the examples working. This is so crazy. I can hide it so I am on the correct view, using the correct navigationitem.

Comment: You can hide back button and then add leftBarButtonItem

Comment: That is a good idea. How do I have a back arrow with that?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
/// This will hide the back button title
private func hideBackButtonTitle(){
    let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
    backButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
    backButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .highlighted)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this simple line of code in your `root/main` `ViewController` -

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Code -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
    }
```

OUTPUT -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following technique to hide the back button. Whenever i **perform segue** OR **push** a new view controller to the navigation stack, i call this function and pass self to the parameter.

```
func clearBackButtonText(vc : UIViewController) {

  let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
  backItem.title = ""
  vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem

}
//call this function in view didLoad of your view controller OR before pushing a view controller on navigation stack
clearBackButtonText(vc: self)
```

---

## See the Example

On Viewdidload of TableVC, i am calling the function

```
class TableVC: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()
       clearBackButtonText(vc: self)
    }
}
```

And On didSelect of a row, i am doing a **push segue** to DetailVC. And my back button is only arrow

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. It turned out that the title of the back button will be set to the title of the view controller that it will go back to. All I had to do is to set the navigationItem.title = " " for the previous ViewController.

Super frustrating...